# Execute If statement, only if element is existed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if($("#Prefix").val().trim()=="" && $("#Infix").val().trim()==""){
    return false;
}
```

In the above code, when the element id `Prefix` or `Infix` does not exist, it's throwing undefined error

```
TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined
```

I know, this can be avoided by checking its length `$("#Prefix").lenght>0` and `$("#Infix").lenght>0`.

My question here is, how can we do both checks inside single `if` statement itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1ugxav9g/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code .  check this [link](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/) explain element length condition

```
 if(($("#Prefix").length && $.trim($("#Prefix").val()) == "") && ($("#Infix").length && $.trim($("#Infix").val())=="")){ 
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Here you adding one more if statement, I want to achieve it inside the same  if statement.

Comment: The first `if` statement can be `if( $("#Prefix, #Infix").length > 1 )`

Comment: @SandeepPatange  only length return 0 or more . if 0 then it become false  so .length and .length similar. as per my knowledge you need to check this 4 condition due to two level validation

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($("#Infix").lenght>0 && $("#Prefix").lenght>0) && ($("#Prefix").val().trim()=="" && $("#Infix").val().trim()=="")){

//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

---

`if` statement with `&&` operator stops checking farther when first `0` is returned. 
`[0 && anything == 0]`.

---

So just check for the `.length` first.

```
if ( ($("#Infix").lenght && $("#Prefix").lenght) && (another conditions) ) {
    ...
}
```